# Notifications failing at notify()

Tags: quasar-framework

I am trying to fire a simple [notification](https://next.quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/notify)  in Quasar 2:

```
setup() {
  const $q = useQuasar()
   $q.notify('hello')
}
```

This fails with:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $q.notify is not a function
```

This is a UMD application that works fine without these two lines - I do not really know where to go from there as the docs say that there is nothing special to configure before using it.

Incindentally, my IDE is suggesting me `notify()` when typing `$q.` so at least at that level is it well recognized.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you forgot to add notify in `plugins`(quasar.conf.js).

```
return {
  framework: {
    plugins: [
      'Notify'
    ],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For those using Vue CLI, you will need to work on `quasar-user-options.js`:

```js
import { Notify } from "quasar";

// To be used on app.use(Quasar, { ... })
export default {
   plugins: { Notify },
};
```

Comment: apparently the same applies to Vite

Answer (score 1):

Quasar vite plugin + vue3

In main.ts or main.js, just add these 2 lines :

```
JS
import { Notify } from "quasar";
.use(Quasar, {
    plugins: {
        Notify,
    }, // import Quasar plugins and add here
})
```

Here a example of my code :

```
JS
import { createApp } from 'vue'

import { Quasar } from 'quasar'
import quasarLang from 'quasar/lang/fr'
import { Notify } from "quasar";
import router from './router'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import './style.css'


// Import icon libraries
import '@quasar/extras/material-icons/material-icons.css'

// Import Quasar css
import 'quasar/src/css/index.sass'

import App from './App.vue'

const pinia = createPinia()

createApp(App)
.use(Quasar, {
    plugins: {
        Notify,
    }, // import Quasar plugins and add here
    lang: quasarLang,
})
.use(router)
.use(pinia)
.mount('#app')
```

Comment: Add language in code block so that it can provide better highlights. Like for Javascript 

```js

Code

```